# convert list of dictionaries to numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that is as follows:

```
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044}
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044}
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044}
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044}
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044}
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044}
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044}
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044}
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044}
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044}
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044}
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044}
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044}
```

I'm trying to convert it to a numpy array with two columns for just the 'x' and 'z' values.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044},
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044},
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044},
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044},
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044},
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044},
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044},
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044},
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044},
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044},
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044},
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044},
{'x': -0.002222188049927354, 'y': 0.014999999664723873, 'z': -0.45333319902420044}]

pd.DataFrame(data)[['x', 'z']].values

array([[-0.00222219, -0.4533332 ],
       [-0.00222219, -0.4533332 ],
       [-0.00222219, -0.4533332 ],
       [-0.00222219, -0.4533332 ],
       [-0.00222219, -0.4533332 ],
       [-0.00222219, -0.4533332 ],
       [-0.00222219, -0.4533332 ],
       [-0.00222219, -0.4533332 ],
       [-0.00222219, -0.4533332 ],
       [-0.00222219, -0.4533332 ],
       [-0.00222219, -0.4533332 ],
       [-0.00222219, -0.4533332 ],
       [-0.00222219, -0.4533332 ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
thearray = pd.DataFrame(dictlist)[['x', 'z']].values
```